# Freezes of JVM/Tomcat under load while safepoint-log logs thausends safepoints "ThreadStop" entries

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a problem with a Java application running in a Tomcat running with openJDK11. The problem is that after some time under high load, the application freezes. The CPU load then also collapses and no more entries are written in Catalina.out or application log files. After some time (1-2 minutes) the system recovers and runs normally.

I first thought that there was a problem with the garbage collection and started the logging for garbage collections and safepoints.

In the Safepoint log there are hundreds to thousands of entries (without interruption of other messages) at freeze times:

```
[2021-02-03T08:53:44.619+0100][5136.564s][info][safepoint] Application time: 0.0153146 seconds
[2021-02-03T08:53:44.620+0100][5136.565s][info][safepoint] Entering safepoint region: ThreadStop
[2021-02-03T08:53:44.621+0100][5136.566s][info][safepoint] Leaving safepoint region
[2021-02-03T08:53:44.621+0100][5136.566s][info][safepoint] Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0020579 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0006463 second
```

The ThreadStop messages correspond 1:1 with the times of the freezes. Therefore the assumption that the ThreadStops are the cause for the problem.

Unfortunately I could not find anything about ThreadStop Safepoints.

Therefore the question, what triggers ThreadStop Safepoints? Are they the cause of the freezes? If so, how can I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: All threads are brought to a safepoint, before GC kicks in. Its the way VM stops all threads to perform a STW event, like a minor or major collection.

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer. Why ThreadStop occurs that often? It there an entry for every single thread that need to be stopped? What can be done to prevent this STW-Event, and stop freezing the Application for minutes?

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadStop` is a VM operation, performed at a global safepoint, to pass an asynchronous exception to some thread.

As of JDK 11, there are two common reasons for such operation:

- [`Thread.stop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) method that delivers an asynchronous `ThreadDeath` error to the given thread;
- JVM TI [`StopThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#StopThread) function.

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) will help to find  where `ThreadStop` is initiated from.

To start profiling asynchronous exceptions, run

```
./profiler.sh start -e Thread::send_async_exception <PID>
```

Then, after one or more `ThreadStop` happened, stop profiling and get the results:

```
./profiler.sh stop -f result.html <PID>
```

[image: ThreadStop profile]

For example, here we see that Tomcat calls `Thread.stop` when reloading a web application. This happens, if an application does not gracefully stop all its threads on its own, and `clearReferencesStopThreads` attribute is set to `true`. See [Context Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) for details.

Comment: Thats just not fair of how good this profiler is!

Comment: I find this just as we are leaving hotspot for graal!